# NodeJS : TypeError: app.use is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am going through the tutorials of [Nodejs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=54aol-U_1es&index=15&list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGBMdkKFn3HasZnnAqVjzHn_) for Connect module.

i have written this code :

```
var http = require('http');
var app = require('connect');
function doFirst(request, response, next) {

    console.log('doFirst');
    next();
}
function doSecond(request, response, next) {

    console.log('doFirst');
    next();
}
app.use(doFirst);
app.use(doSecond);
http.createServer(app).listen(8888);
```

and while running this application facing issue :

```
C:\Users\sparsh\eclipse-workspace\Delete\ConnectServer.js:13
app.use(doFirst);
    ^

TypeError: app.use is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\sparsh\eclipse-workspace\Delete\ConnectServer.js:13:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:158:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:575:3
```

Please help

Comment: Just curious, why are you using the (rather old) connect module instead of using `express`?

Comment: B'coz i am in learning phase and i am not aware about the new updation happen about Node.
So for the sake of getting the basic knowledge i am following the tutorial given in the link

Answer (score 2):

As jfriend00 mentioned in the comments: Use express ;)

But to answer your question. `require( 'connect' )` returns a function. What you need to do is:

```
var http = require('http');
var connect = require('connect');

var app = connect();
// ...
```

Also see the npm package [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect)

Answer (score 1):

Before declaring app.use you have to:

```
var app = app();
```

OR better

```
var connect = require("connect");

var app = connect();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just replace the first two line using the below code:

```
var connect = require('connect');
var http = require('http');

var app = connect();
```

For more details please read [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const connect = require('connect');
const http = require('http');

const app = connect();

app.use(doFirst);
app.use(doSecond);
```